# EAAcessory unable to list device with showBluetoothAccessoryPickerWithNameFilter: method

Tags: ios, bluetooth, eaaccessory

I am using this method

```
 [[EAAccessoryManager sharedAccessoryManager] showBluetoothAccessoryPickerWithNameFilter:nil completion:^(NSError *error) {
}
```

to list out available bluetooth devices which are in MFI program. It shows the picker but there is no list of devices unlike other answers on stackoverflow that It should show the devices in list. I am normally able to connect up mobile and External device by going in settings and also successfully passed values. But I want to do it without going manually to settings inside app. Am I missing something! 
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Where did you add code?

Comment: I have used the above method on a button click!

Answer (score 1):

Did you add protocol string to your Info.plist?

In apple documents.

> Note: The picker displays only Bluetooth devices that include an iAP
>   over Bluetooth unique ID in their extended inquiry response.

You need protocol string of Device to be added in "Supported external accessory protocols"

Comment: Yes, I have did that and included the above key pair in my plist. I am using iOS 6.1.3 and this method is available from iOS 6, so where is the problem!